# JQuery UI 'draggable is not a function' Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I am trying to use JQuery draggable on rows within a table, but keep receiving the error '$(...).draggable is not a function'. In my code I have checked the versions of JQuery and JQuery UI (3.6.0 and 1.12.1) and also that they have loaded before I try to use the draggable function. I can use sortable on the tbody and it works fine so I don't know where this error is coming from. Any help would be great, thanks.

HTML

```
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>1</tr>
   <tr>2</tr>
   <tr>3</tr>
   <tr>4</tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    if (window.jQuery && window.jQuery.ui) {
        $("tr").draggable({
            appendTo: "tbody",
            helper: "clone"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Create your table properly and try. You are missing `<td>`. `<table><tbody><tr><td>1</td></tr>.....` It's work when I try proper formatted table.

Comment: Your example looks like it should work if the jQuery and jQuery UI Libraries are loaded. You did not include a complete example, so there is no way yo know why the error is appearing. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  if (window.jQuery && window.jQuery.ui) {
    $("table tbody tr").draggable({
      appendTo: "tbody",
      helper: "clone"
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Each Row is draggable in this example.